# JavaScript string replace is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, charat

I am writing a program which takes three parameters e.g, sentence, wordtoreplace, toReplaceWith.

program should return sentence string with wordtoreplace should be replaced with toReplaceWith. And if the wordtoreplace is a capitalized word then the replaced world should also be capitalized. I tried many times but my code doesn't work. Help please.

```js
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  var words = str.split(" ");
  var indexOfWord = words.indexOf(before);
  
    if ( before.charAt(0) === before.charAt(0).toUpperCase ) {
      after = capitalize(after);
    }
   str = str.replace(new RegExp(before), after);
   
      function capitalize( word ) {
      return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
      }
   return str.replace(new RegExp(after, 'i', 'g'), after);;
}

myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped");
```

Comment: Why do you split the string in words? Note that `RegExp` does not take three arguments. You need to call `toUpperCase()` with parentheses. You don't use *words* or *indexOfWord* once they are initialised. Why do you have them? But it seems a bit redundant to apply the capitalisation when the caller of your function could easily provide the capital letter? It makes the function non-user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably invoke `toUpperCase` within your `if` statement

`if ( before.charAt(0) === before.charAt(0).toUpperCase() ) {
      after = capitalize(after);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  var words = str.split(" ");
  var indexOfWord = words.indexOf(before);

  if ( before.charAt(0) == before.charAt(0).toUpperCase() ) {
     after = capitalize(after);
  }
  str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + before + '\\b'), after);

  function capitalize( word ) {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
  }
  return str.replace(new RegExp(after, 'i', 'g'), after);;
}
```

You can use '\\b' for find in the string.
You can test the code here: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBQS72BU7H97

Here the doc:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_begin.asp

Comment: sorry but it is not working if the the before starts with an uppercase letter it doesn't replace with after.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the parenthesis at the `.toUpperCase()` function in your `if` statement.

I have also tried to make your version a bit cleaner, maybe it will help you.

```
function replace(sentence, wordToReplaced, newWord) {
  if (sentence.includes(wordToReplaced)) {
    var char = wordToReplaced.charAt(0);
    if (char === char.toUpperCase()) {
      newWord = newWord.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newWord.slice(1);
    }
    sentence = sentence.replace(wordToReplaced, newWord);
  }
  return sentence;
}
```